# Memory usage measurement of modules in Drupal 7

Tags: memory-leaks, drupal-7, shared-memory

I use shared hosting, they didn't allow more than 32MB memory for my site.
When i add 10-15 modules Drupal 7 gives fatal error, memory was exhausted.
So i look for the modules that spends memory most.

I found this which is for earlier versions of Drupal.

http://2bits.com/articles/measuring-memory-consumption-by-drupal-bootstrap-and-modules.html

Can you recommend me a tool/code etc. to measure the memory usage of modules?
I installed devel, but couldn't find how to measure it.

Thank you

edit: I mean "memory_limit". Error message is "Fatal Error: PHP Allowed Memory Size Exhausted (tried to allocate … bytes) in ...".

Comment: Physical memory? Virtual memory? Resident set? It's not clear what you mean by "32MB memory". It's not clear what you want to measure.

Comment: Sorry to be the one to tell you, but that kind of setup will never be able to run Drupal 7 comfortably.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been made into a separate module. Its also got a Drupal 7 port. Check http://drupal.org/project/performance.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and based on my Google search, clearing the 'accesslog' table helped, as it had around 4L rows and during the loading, drupal tries to index those records. Somebody says to disable it totally. However, I decided to wipe off the records as they are not that significant to me.